# USB relay DLL problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I got USB relay which I need to program so that in specified times it would open for some time and then close. I tried to integrate DLL provided to me, but couldn't do it (or maybe I just did something wrong). Also tried to find some guide how to do this, also without success.

USB relay: songle srd-05vdc-sl-c

I am using VS 2013 and I am trying to make simple C# application.
Also maybe there is something else wrong because HIDAPI GUI application does not show my relay as connected device.
I am sitting on Windows 8 if that changes anything.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or what the issue is that you are actually trying to solve.. If you were asked this question, what would you need to solve it?

Comment: I am asking for a guide how to implement USB relay API in my C# project. I tried HIDAPI, but that did not show my device. I am new to programming relays, though it should be an easy task

Comment: Then your question is off topic - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I already thought that this is gonna be the answer. I made a new project in VS 2013 and did everything GUI related (there are options to define times when the relay should open and that's all) and got the part where I would send command to relay to open, but the DLL which came with it was no good as I could not get it to work (strictly following README provided), that's why I came here to see if anyone has ever tried something like this, because even Google would not find a thing.

Comment: We cannot help you because we don't know what DLL you're talking about  and we don't have the README provided.

Comment: Here is DLL what I am using - http://files.fm/u/fjyjhku , but I can't get it to work

Comment: Very difficult to know what you are doing wrong without seeing any of your code as well. Is the Relay seen in the device manager, so that you know it is connected - if not then have you followed the instructions to get the appropriate driver loaded. Does the relay/DLL come with any test code?

Comment: @DoubleT What you have is for C++/C. You might get it to work with [pinvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your DLL is an C++ or C library with exports, you can use platform invoke to call methods in the dll.

Using the files you provided in the comments <sup>([mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/download/j6vqnjeccqjjrcc/usb_relay_dll.zip) - 16.06.2015)</sup>, here's what your wrapper could look like. There may be errors so please treat this like an example. I added XML comments based on the comments in the header file.

Note that in order for this to work, you need to place `usb_relay_device.dll` in the same folder as your C# executable. The best way to do this is to add the file to your project and set "*Copy to Output Directory*" in VS's Solution Explorer to *Copy Always* or *Copy if newer*.

**Note**: As noted in the comments, if the example throws an error about an unbalanced stack, add `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` to the `DllImport` attribute, or try another [calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention).

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UsbRelay
{
    public static class UsbRelayDevice
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Init the USB Relay Libary
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This function returns 0 on success and -1 on error.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_init")]
        public static extern int Init();

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalize the USB Relay Libary.
        /// This function frees all of the static data associated with
        /// USB Relay Libary. It should be called at the end of execution to avoid
        /// memory leaks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This function returns 0 on success and -1 on error.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_exit")]
        public static extern int Exit();

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerate the USB Relay Devices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_enumerate")]
        public static extern UsbRelayDeviceInfo Enumerate();

        /// <summary>
        /// Free an enumeration Linked List
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="deviceInfo"></param>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_free_enumerate")]
        public static extern void FreeEnumerate(UsbRelayDeviceInfo deviceInfo);

        /// <summary>
        /// Open device that serial number is serialNumber
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serialNumber"></param>
        /// <param name="stringLength"></param>
        /// <returns>This funcation returns a valid handle to the device on success or NULL on failure.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_with_serial_number", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int OpenWithSerialNumber([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string serialNumber, int stringLength);

        /// <summary>
        /// Open a usb relay device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="deviceInfo"></param>
        /// <returns>This funcation returns a valid handle to the device on success or NULL on failure.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open")]
        public static extern int Open(UsbRelayDeviceInfo deviceInfo);

        /// <summary>
        /// Close a usb relay device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle"></param>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close")]
        public static extern void Close(int hHandle);

        /// <summary>
        /// open a relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">Which usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <param name="index">Which channel your want to open</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error; 2 -- index is outnumber the number of the usb relay device</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_one_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int OpenOneRelayChannel(int hHandle, int index);

        /// <summary>
        /// open all relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">which usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_all_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int OpenAllRelayChannels(int hHandle);

        /// <summary>
        /// close a relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">which usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <param name="index">which channel your want to close</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error; 2 -- index is outnumber the number of the usb relay device</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close_one_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int CloseOneRelayChannel(int hHandle, int index);

        /// <summary>
        /// close all relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">hich usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close_all_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int CloseAllRelayChannels(int hHandle);

        /// <summary>
        /// status bit: High --> Low 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000, one bit indicate a relay status.
        /// the lowest bit 0 indicate relay one status, 1 -- means open status, 0 -- means closed status.
        /// bit 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 indicate relay 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 status
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle"></param>
        /// <param name="status"></param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_get_status")]
        public static extern int GetStatus(int hHandle, ref int status);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// USB relay board info structure
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
    public class UsbRelayDeviceInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string SerialNumber;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string DevicePath;

        public UsbRelayDeviceType Type;

        public UsbRelayDeviceInfo Next;
    }

    public enum UsbRelayDeviceType
    {
        OneChannel = 1,
        TwoChannel = 2,
        FourChannel = 4,
        EightChannel = 8
    }
}
```

To open the relay channel 1 in your device, you could do something like this:

```
if (UsbRelayDevice.Init() != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't initialize!");
    return;
}
string serial = "serial number here";
int deviceHandle = UsbRelayDevice.OpenWithSerialNumber(serial, serial.Length);
int openResult = UsbRelayDevice.OpenOneRelayChannel(deviceHandle, 1);
if (openResult == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got error from OpenOneRelayChannel!");
    return;
}
else if (openResult == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index is out of range on the usb relay device");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this great piece of code. I modified it so it would not give any errors (made the DLL's methods extern) and seems like there is some other problem, because Enumerate() doesn't return any results. When I plug my device in USB port it displays as unrecognized device. I copied the DLL into Output directory, so that should be ok. Have to keep digging, but at least there is progress.

Comment: @DoubleT If the first `Enumerate()` returns anything, you should be able to traverse the linked list by accessing the `Next` property.

Comment: Also, thanks! I added in the externs.

Comment: @DoubleT Did your device come with any drivers to install? Does the manufacturer offer any drivers?

Comment: Device did not come with any drivers. And I did not found anything in manufacturer's site.

Comment: I figured out I was looking for wrong driver. I needed ATMEL Tiny45 driver, but after installing various stuff from their site I still cannot launch it as recognised device.

Comment: Im getting this error while using this code
"Attribute 'MarshalAs' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field, param, return' declarations" . How to avoid this?

Comment: Thanks for this example. This is the first time I needed to deal with something like this.  One thing I would add is, if you run this code and get an "Unbalanced" error, add this to the DllImport… CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl