# USB relay DLL problems - Continues

Tags: c#, c++, dll

There is a quesion about this under this [USB relay DLL problems [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869629/usb-relay-dll-problems). There is a good acceptable answer given by [cubrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996081/cubrr). But there is a code giving me an error when I tryed to compile the program. Error says that

> Attribute 'MarshalAs' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'field, param, return' declarations

Here is the the [cubrr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996081/cubrr) code

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UsbRelay
{
    public static class UsbRelayDevice
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Init the USB Relay Libary
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This function returns 0 on success and -1 on error.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_init")]
        public static extern int Init();

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalize the USB Relay Libary.
        /// This function frees all of the static data associated with
        /// USB Relay Libary. It should be called at the end of execution to avoid
        /// memory leaks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This function returns 0 on success and -1 on error.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_exit")]
        public static extern int Exit();

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerate the USB Relay Devices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_enumerate")]
        public static extern UsbRelayDeviceInfo Enumerate();

        /// <summary>
        /// Free an enumeration Linked List
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="deviceInfo"></param>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_free_enumerate")]
        public static extern void FreeEnumerate(UsbRelayDeviceInfo deviceInfo);

        /// <summary>
        /// Open device that serial number is serialNumber
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serialNumber"></param>
        /// <param name="stringLength"></param>
        /// <returns>This funcation returns a valid handle to the device on success or NULL on failure.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_with_serial_number", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int OpenWithSerialNumber([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string serialNumber, int stringLength);

        /// <summary>
        /// Open a usb relay device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="deviceInfo"></param>
        /// <returns>This funcation returns a valid handle to the device on success or NULL on failure.</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open")]
        public static extern int Open(UsbRelayDeviceInfo deviceInfo);

        /// <summary>
        /// Close a usb relay device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle"></param>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close")]
        public static extern void Close(int hHandle);

        /// <summary>
        /// open a relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">Which usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <param name="index">Which channel your want to open</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error; 2 -- index is outnumber the number of the usb relay device</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_one_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int OpenOneRelayChannel(int hHandle, int index);

        /// <summary>
        /// open all relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">which usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_all_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int OpenAllRelayChannels(int hHandle);

        /// <summary>
        /// close a relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">which usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <param name="index">which channel your want to close</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error; 2 -- index is outnumber the number of the usb relay device</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close_one_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int CloseOneRelayChannel(int hHandle, int index);

        /// <summary>
        /// close all relay channel on the USB-Relay-Device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle">hich usb relay device your want to operate</param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close_all_relay_channel")]
        public static extern int CloseAllRelayChannels(int hHandle);

        /// <summary>
        /// status bit: High --> Low 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000, one bit indicate a relay status.
        /// the lowest bit 0 indicate relay one status, 1 -- means open status, 0 -- means closed status.
        /// bit 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 indicate relay 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 status
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHandle"></param>
        /// <param name="status"></param>
        /// <returns>0 -- success; 1 -- error</returns>
        [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_get_status")]
        public static extern int GetStatus(int hHandle, ref int status);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// USB relay board info structure
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
    public class UsbRelayDeviceInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] //Error is here
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] //Error is here
        public string DevicePath { get; set; }

        public UsbRelayDeviceType Type { get; set; }

        public UsbRelayDeviceInfo Next { get; set; }
    }

    public enum UsbRelayDeviceType
    {
        OneChannel = 1,
        TwoChannel = 2,
        FourChannel = 4,
        EightChannel = 8
    }
}
```

Error in Here

```
/// <summary>
        /// USB relay board info structure
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
        public class UsbRelayDeviceInfo
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] //Error is here
            public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] //Error is here
            public string DevicePath { get; set; }

            public UsbRelayDeviceType Type { get; set; }

            public UsbRelayDeviceInfo Next { get; set; }
        }
```

Please help me to solve this

[Here is the Hardware part details](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-Channel-USB-Relay-5V-Programmable-Computer-Control-For-Smart-Home-/161769705825?hash=item25aa39d161)

[Here is the SDK that provide by hardware vender](http://www.winddeal.net/image/tools/26484%20%2026483%20USBRelayExtLib.rar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you the exact problem.

Properties, even auto-properties, can't be marshalled.  Only plain old fields.

Change

```
public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
 //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //                        REMOVE THIS
```

to

```
public string SerialNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben Voigt. Now its running well :D

Comment: But can not get the Serial number from device

Comment: Still Can not get UsbRelayDeviceInfo. Can you help me plz

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar relay and the wrapper included on [this](http://forum.banggood.com/forum-topic-27617.html) post worked better for me, specifically with getting device serial number:

```
public enum usb_relay_device_type
{
    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_ONE_CHANNEL = 1,
    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_TWO_CHANNEL = 2,
    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_FOUR_CHANNEL = 4,
    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_EIGHT_CHANNEL = 8
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct usb_relay_device_info
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string serial_number;
    public IntPtr device_path { get; set; }
    public usb_relay_device_type type { get; set; }
    public IntPtr next { get; set; }
}

public class RelayDeviceWrapper
{
    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_enumerate",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    //[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    private static extern IntPtr Pusb_relay_device_enumerate();

    public static usb_relay_device_info usb_relay_device_enumerate()
    {
        IntPtr x = RelayDeviceWrapper.Pusb_relay_device_enumerate();
        usb_relay_device_info a = (usb_relay_device_info)Marshal.PtrToStructure(x, typeof(usb_relay_device_info));
        return a;
    }

    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_init", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int usb_relay_init();


    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_with_serial_number", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int usb_relay_device_open_with_serial_number([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string serial_number, int len);


    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void usb_relay_device_close(int hHandle);

    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_all_relay_channel", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int usb_relay_device_open_all_relay_channel(int hHandle);


    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close_all_relay_channel", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int usb_relay_device_close_all_relay_channel(int hHandle);


    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_close_one_relay_channel", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int usb_relay_device_close_one_relay_channel(int hHandle, int index);


    [DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", EntryPoint = "usb_relay_device_open_one_relay_channel", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int usb_relay_device_open_one_relay_channel(int hHandle, int index);
}
```

Then you can control your relay with the following code:

```
    if (RelayDeviceWrapper.usb_relay_init() != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't initialize!");
        return;
    }
    else { Console.WriteLine("Initialized successfully!"); }

    usb_relay_device_info deviceInfo = RelayDeviceWrapper.usb_relay_device_enumerate();

    string serial = deviceInfo.serial_number;
    int deviceHandle = RelayDeviceWrapper.usb_relay_device_open_with_serial_number(serial, serial.Length);
    int openResult = RelayDeviceWrapper.usb_relay_device_open_all_relay_channel(deviceHandle);

    if (openResult == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No error returned from usb_relay_device_open_one_relay_channel!");
    }
    else if (openResult == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got error from OpenOneRelayChannel!");
        return;
    }

    RelayDeviceWrapper.usb_relay_device_close(deviceHandle);
```